# Sql Data Sync How to rename the metadata object

Tags: synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I am developing custom application to sync data between azure database and sql database using sql sync framewrok 2.1.
I need to easily identify the object that has been created by sync framework.

For example by default sync framework create **dbo.scope_info**  for tracking metadata. i need to rename this table as **SqlDataSync.scope_info**

Is this possible using sync framewrok. if possible what are the steps need to follow.

THank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify an ObjectPrefix or even an ObjectSchema when provisioning, just look it up on the documentation

Answer (score 0):

here is the link to microsoft documentation
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.synchronization.data.sqlserverce.sqlcesyncscopeprovisioning.objectprefix%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

To set the object prefix 
 SqlSyncScopeProvisioning serverConfig = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning((SqlConnection)syncProvider.Connection);
 serverConfig.ObjectPrefix = "Sync";

To set the Schema prefix 
 SqlSyncScopeProvisioning serverConfig = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning((SqlConnection)syncProvider.Connection);
           serverConfig.ObjectSchema ="MySync";